# How can i make samsung S5 to be shown as a drive when i connect it to my PC?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung-galaxy-s-5

when i connect the phone via USB it shows as Portable device; but i want it to be as a drive so i can review my files on the labtop.
note: i have S3 and S5 with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the USB sign on the notification bar.
Then in the new page, check the "Media Device(MTP)" and wait for few seconds to see the drive show up in your computer/mac.

Comment: Thanks Sam Ramezanli's. I did what you adviced me so many times and it still the same; shows as portaple device!

Comment: are you a windows or Mac User?